# laravel 5.5 jwt issue

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-5.5

I got an issue when I tried to use jwt with laravel "5.5" (**this issue only happen on version 5.5**)

[I'm following this tutorial](http://laravelcode.com/post/restful-api-in-laravel-55-using-jwt-authentication)

and I got this error when I tried to post on postMan

**Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\NamshiAdapter' not found**

[errorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch2Mh.png)

plz help.

I put this issue on github, here is link:

---

> h ttps://github.com/jimmyHuey/jwt-test

---

Comment: Please show some code you've tried.

Comment: you probably didn't import the class on top... something like: `use Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\NamshiAdapter` or you didn't register it in service provider... maybe it's an older version of that package that doesn't have auto discovery?

Comment: @Dream_Cap 
 thanks for reply, I already put this issue on github
https://github.com/jimmyHuey/jwt-test

Comment: @lewis4u  sorry, I'm newbie on laravel. Can you tell me where (or which file) to put this import? thanks for help! :)
I already put this issue on github:[link](http://github.com/jimmyHuey/jwt-test)

Comment: Never mind I found it....you need to setup a config file did you do that? you must have this file `config/jwt.php`

Comment: yes, I had.  I use php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider"   to generate the jwt.php file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found my problem.
on config/jwt.php file change following provider :

1. NamshiAdapter to Namshi
2. IlluminateAuthAdapter to Illuminate
3. IlluminateCacheAdapter to Illuminate

---

then I got this error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Tymon\JWTAuth\JWT::fromUser() must be an instance of Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject, instance of App\User given, called in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/git/jwt-test/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/JWTAuth.php on line 54

I fix it by implement JWTSubject and modify the class:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by just looking the [#1316 issue](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1316) .

Still can't figure out what's wrong with my project, but at least I find a way to use jwt-auth on laravel 5.5